# What should I do to delete the id of the object data in the list?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I send the data first, then there is no problem, but when I want to update, I can delete
the root object's id, but I could not delete the id of the objects in the list.
Any ideas what can I do?

```
  const handleSubmit = async (values: any) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if (!id) {
      usersService
        .create(values)
        .then((response) => {
          saved(response.data._id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          message.error(`${t("error")} ${error.response.data.message}`);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }
    if (id) {
      const formData = { ...result, ...values };
      console.log(formData);
      delete formData._id;
      delete formData.createdAt;
      delete formData.updatedAt;
      delete formData.List.map((x : any) => x._id) // this didn't work
      delete formData.enrolledCourses;
      delete formData.isProfileCompleted;
      usersService
        .update(id, formData)
        .then(() => {
          saved();
          rowHighlight(id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          message.error(`${t("error")} ${error.response.data.message}`);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }
  };
```

I tried the map function and forEach functions.
I tried to delete the returned values ​​inside and outside the function but couldn't find it.

Comment: map returns a new array for you based on  the function you give it. In this case it returns an array of ids back to you which doesn't seem like it's what you want to delete. I think what you are looking for is more like `Array.find()` or maybe even `Array.filter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map every list item and remove their id property like this :

```
formData.List.map((x : any) => {
   const newX = {...x};
   delete newX._id;
   return newX
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said and additionally reassigned the formData.List and it worked.